# Mail app always shows most recently read email

Tags: ipad, email, mobile-mail

When I open the Mail app on my iPad the last email read is always displayed. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: @ClareMacrae I would prefer that the right-hand window was just empty.

Comment: Ah right. I had a look through the Settings for email, and couldn't see anything to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to adjust this behaviour on iOS with the current version (iOS 6.1 and prior)